# Using a gsm/gprs shield with a separate gps shield on arduino uno

Tags: gps, arduino

I have been trying to get gps data from my gps shield and then send to a web server using the gprs shield on arduino uno to no avail.
I am using Seeduino's gprs shield v2.0b with sim 900 and gps v1.1 shield.
I am able to get gps data separately and also send to my web server separately but on combining the two, it stops working entirely.
Both are using Software serial but on different ports.

My Entire code is below

```
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include "inetGSM.h"
#include "sms.h"
//#include "call.h"
//#include "gps.h"
#include <TinyGPS.h>
//#include <String.h>


//To change pins for Software Serial, use the two lines in GSM.cpp.

//GSM Shield for Arduino
//www.open-electronics.org
//this code is based on the example of Arduino Labs.

//Simple sketch to start a connection as client.
/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
 It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
 4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 3(rx) and 4(tx).
 */

SoftwareSerial ss(3, 4);
TinyGPS gps;

const char sid[]= "ARDUINO1";
unsigned long fix_age,time,date;
float vspeed,vcourse ;
float flat, flon;
unsigned long age;
long mycounter=0;
boolean gotgpsdata=false;


//InetGSM inet;
//CallGSM call;
SMSGSM sms;
//GPSGSM gpss;
 char* longg;
    char* latt;
   char* speddd;
   char* dateee;
   char* timeee;
   int count=0;
 char final[150]="A1,";
char stat;
char msg[50];
int numdata;
char inSerial[50];
int i=0;
boolean started=false;

void setup() 
{

  //Serial connection.
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("GSM Shield testing.");  
  ss.begin(9600);  
  //gsm.begin(19200);
  delay(5000);  
  Serial.print("Simple TinyGPS library v. "); 
  Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println();
  gotgpsdata=false;  
}

void sendsms(char data[])
{

  if (gsm.begin(19200)){
    Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
    started=true;  
    gsm.forceON();
  }
  else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");

  if(started){
    //Enable this two lines if you want to send an SMS.   
    if (sms.SendSMS("+234xxxxxxx", data))
      Serial.println("\nSMS sent OK");
      delay(3000);
  }  
}

void dogprsaction(char data[])
{ 
    if (gsm.begin(19200)){
    Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
    started=true;  
    gsm.forceON();
  }
  else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");
  delay(10000);

  if(started){
    //GPRS attach, put in order APN, username and password.
    //If no needed auth let them blank.
    if (inet.attachGPRS("internet.ng.airtel.com", "internet", "internet"))
      Serial.println("status=ATTACHED");
    else Serial.println("status=ERROR");
    delay(1000);

    //Read IP address.
    gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CIFSR");
    delay(5000);
    //Read until serial buffer is empty.
    gsm.WhileSimpleRead();

    //TCP Client GET, send a GET request to the server and
    //my server aaddress goes here
    numdata=inet.httpGET("www.google.com", 80,"/?q=hello", msg, 50);
    //Print the results.
    Serial.println("\nNumber of data received:");
    Serial.println(numdata);  
    Serial.println("\nData received:"); 
    Serial.println(msg); 
    //ss.flush();
    gotgpsdata=false;
  }
  //inet.dettachGPRS();

}

int getgpsdata()
{
 strcpy(final,"A1,");
 // ss.listen();
  //ss.begin(9600);//9600);
  delay(2000);  
 // Serial.println("starting gps");
  boolean newData = false;
  gotgpsdata=false; 
  unsigned long chars;
  unsigned short sentences, failed;  

  // For one second we parse GPS data and report some key values
  for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 1000;)
  {
    while (ss.available())
    {
      char c = ss.read();
      // Serial.print(c); // uncomment this line if you want to see the GPS data flowing
      if (gps.encode(c)) // Did a new valid sentence come in?
      {
        newData = true;
      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
  }

  if (newData)
  {

    gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
    Serial.print("SYSTEM ID = ");
    Serial.print(sid);
    Serial.print(" LAT=");
    Serial.print(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flat, 6);
    Serial.print(" LON=");
    Serial.print(flon == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flon, 6);
    Serial.print(" SAT=");
    Serial.print(gps.satellites() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES ? 0 : gps.satellites());
    Serial.print(" PREC=");
    Serial.print(gps.hdop() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP ? 0 : gps.hdop());
    Serial.print(" DATE=");
    gps.get_datetime(&date, &time, &fix_age);
    Serial.print(date);
    Serial.print(" TIME=");
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.print(" SPEED=");
    vspeed=gps.f_speed_kmph();
    Serial.print(vspeed);
    Serial.print("km/hr");
    gotgpsdata=true;
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println(flon); 
     char longitude[30]="ARDUINO"; 
   char latitude[30]="ARDUINO"; 
 char speedd[30]="ARDUINO";  
char datee[30]="ARDUINO";  
char timee[30]="ARDUINO"; 
    longg= dtostrf(flon,1,4,&longitude[15]);
    latt= dtostrf(flat,1,4,&latitude[15]);
    speddd= dtostrf(vspeed,1,4,&speedd[15]);
    dateee= dtostrf(date,1,0,&datee[15]);
    timeee= dtostrf(time,1,0,&timee[15]);
   char* all="ARDUINO";
   Serial.print("LON:");
   Serial.print(longg);
   Serial.print(",LAT: ");
   Serial.print(latt);
    Serial.print(",SPEED: ");
   Serial.print(speddd);
    Serial.print(",DATE: ");
   Serial.print(dateee);
    Serial.print(",TIME: ");
   Serial.print(timeee);
   Serial.println();
   int longlength=strlen(longg);
   int latlength=strlen(latt);
   int spdlength=strlen(speddd);
   int datelength=strlen(dateee);
   int timelength=strlen(timeee);  

   int totallength=longlength+latlength+spdlength+datelength+timelength;  

   int counter=0;
   strcat(final,longg);
   strcat(final,",");
    strcat(final,latt);
   strcat(final,",");
    strcat(final,speddd);
   strcat(final,",");
    strcat(final,dateee);
   strcat(final,",");
    strcat(final,timeee);
  // strcat(final,",");

   Serial.println(final);

  }

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  Serial.print(" CHARS=");
  Serial.print(chars);
  Serial.print(" SENTENCES=");
  Serial.print(sentences);
  Serial.print(" CSUM ERR=");
  Serial.println(failed);
  Serial.println();
  delay(2000);
  return 12;
}


void loop() 
{
  ss.begin(9600);
  getgpsdata();
  ss.end(); 
  if(gotgpsdata==true)
  {    
    dogprsaction(final);
  }

  serialhwread();
  //Read for new byte on NewSoftSerial.
  serialswread();

};

void serialhwread(){
  i=0;
  if (Serial.available() > 0){            
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      inSerial[i]=(Serial.read());
      delay(10);
      i++;      
    }

    inSerial[i]='\0';
    if(!strcmp(inSerial,"/END")){
      Serial.println("_");
      inSerial[0]=0x1a;
      inSerial[1]='\0';
      gsm.SimpleWriteln(inSerial);
    }
    //Send a saved AT command using serial port.
    if(!strcmp(inSerial,"TEST")){
      Serial.println("SIGNAL QUALITY");
      gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CSQ");
    }
    //Read last message saved.
    if(!strcmp(inSerial,"MSG")){
      Serial.println(msg);
    }
    else{
      Serial.println(inSerial);
      gsm.SimpleWriteln(inSerial);
    }    
    inSerial[0]='\0';
  }
}

void serialswread(){
  gsm.SimpleRead();
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind adding some extra details about your problem to your question? Please provide the code you've already tried.

When you say `It stopped working entirely`: What do you mean by that? Can you provide some error messages or some more details? Adding the mentioned information will increase the chances for help. Not doing so may lead to the question being deleted or closed by the moderators.

Comment: This is the entire code i've written, if i remove the dogprsaction() function from the loop, the gps alone works,but when i add it it stops working,

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We resolved the issue by switching to AltSoftSerial. There is a demo of the working tracker, with code on our site here
http://www.mallinson-electrical.com/shop/gpsgsm
I hope this helps